# what should I do if my question with bounty has no correct answer?

Tags: support, bounties

I've read [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) and I found this:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted   answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

I asked a question and I started a bounty in [set jquery ThickBox size to auto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16495069/1427849) !

If I don't get a correct answer within my bounty period , can I ask this question with more bounty or what should I do ?

Comment: You can add another bounty, yes, once this one has expired. It has to be higher than the previous bounty you set.

Comment: You could just be throwing good money after bad. If the question initially didn't get any good answers, *still* didn't get any good answers after a bounty was placed on it then it's possibly a sign that there *isn't* a good answer out there, or there isn't anyone out there able to answer it.

Comment: Or, potentially, that you haven't asked it very well. I don't know enough about the subject to say either way.